# Change partition size on a Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, partition

I'm trying to transfer 60 GB of free space from D:\ to my system partition C:\
With the disk manager I was able to remove 60 GB from D:.

Assigning it to C:\ seems to be problem, because the empty space is now behind D:\ and can't be assigned to C:.

Therefore I have two options:

- Delete D:\ , assign the desired amount of GB to C:\ , recreate D:\
- Use a third party software to do this job

Option 1) is far too painful, because D:\ is in heavy use.
Option 2) seems to lack the availability of free / cheap software. 160 $ for a single server license is too expensive.

Are there any good partition managers available, that don't cost a fortune?

(The server is hosted in a data center. I'm only allowed to connect via a remote desktop connection)

Comment: Any possibility of getting DRAC or similar remote console access?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task, I needed to move my system partition to another disk. I found my solution as follows:

- used Clonezilla to clone the system partition to the new disk
- after Clonezille you can resize your partition as you need
- started old windows to correct fs errors
- used XX Clone to "make partition bootable" (old disk was still connected)
- disconnected old hdd
- run windows rescue CD -> repair existing windows os
- reboot and go

sincerely tingle2k

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php/). Boot it up, then move the partition used by the D: volume to the end (far right) of the disk. You can then resize the partition used by the C: volume.

As always when doing things with partitions, make sure you have a backup in case things go horribly wrong.

**Update:** Sorry, I just noticed that you only have RDP access. You might be out of luck, I don't know of any way to do what you want that would work over RDP, sorry.

Comment: He says server is remote location in a datacenter. How will he reboot with a livecd without external help?

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to a console for example using VNC then you could use for example a Linux LiveCD with GParted to move a partition - I think it is possible, but dangerous - make sure you have created a good, tested backup first.

Simpler and safer would be to create a new partition and mount it under a directory which needs more space - Windows can do this easily. First move all data from this directory to a new partition (make sure to also copy metadata, like permissions) and then mount it to this, now empty, directory.